# Accept only PDF file for upload

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

When I initially use the `MediaUpload` component and I choose to upload an image, it only lets me upload a PDF and all other files types in my computer file manager are greyed out. This is good. However when I want to change it all file types are available to choose from even though I have specified the mime type `application/pdf`.

```
          {!pdfUrl && (
            <MediaPlaceholder
              value={pdfID}
              labels={{ title: "PDF" }}
              onSelect={onPdfSelect}
              accept=".pdf"
            />
          )}
          {pdfUrl && (
            <MediaUploadCheck>
              <MediaUpload
                onSelect={onPdfSelect}
                allowedTypes={['application/pdf']}
                value={pdfID}
                accept=".pdf"
                render={({ open }) => (
                  <IconButton
                    className="components-toolbar__control"
                    label="Replace PDF"
                    icon="edit"
                    onClick={open}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </MediaUploadCheck>
          )}
```